# p5.js - sketch.js tries to download tar-files

Tags: p5.js, sketch.js

I have a webpage where I integrated p5 and sketch.js for a canvas animation.

The page tries to download arbitrary tar-files every now and then and I can't figure out why.

I disabled CCapture and all the keystrokes that seem to trigger a download.

Any ideas why this is happening?

[edit] as per request

Files are downloaded from here:

```
<script src="https://Unpkg.com/ccapture.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.js"></script>
```

And this is the code:

```
var DEBUG = false; // Set this to false before capturing

var ENK = [85.5, 85.7, 86.6, 87.7, 88.5]; //ENK Werte aus der Studie
var WNK = [89.6, 89.8, 90.3, 91.0, 91.8]; //WNK Werte aus der Studie
var DURATION = 100// In frames / 2
var TRANSITION_DURATION =1000; // In frames
var STEPS = 20;
var COUNT;
var C;

var ns = [0.004, 0.003, 0.004]; // NOISE SCALES array // Ausgangswert Noise Scale
var transition = { oX: ns[0], oY: ns[1], tX: ns[0], tY: ns[1], t: 0, ing: false }; //Smooth transition/Positionsänderung
var look = 0;
var phase;

var capturer, cnvs;

// SETUP wird nur einmal abgerufen und bleibt deshalb immer gleich
function setup() {

  var moodImageDiv = document.getElementById('moodImage');

  var canvas = createCanvas(moodImageDiv.offsetWidth, moodImageDiv.offsetHeight);
  canvas.parent('moodImage');
  //setupCCapture(); // Uncomment this to set up capturing

  
  C = {

    bg1: color(69, 6, 19),
    bg2: color(150, 0, 60), // Hintergrund Farbe Bordeaux
    bg3: color(240, 70,107),

    a: color(245, 60, 105),
    b: color(140, 40, 135), //Linien Farben
    c: color(255, 70, 107),
    d: color(145, 30, 100) 

  };
  
  background(0);
  strokeWeight(0.5);
  noFill();
  COUNT = round(width * 1.5 / STEPS);
  
  changeLook(0); // Uncomment this to start with Look #1 instead of #0
  
}


// UPDATE wird immer wieder aufgerufen
function update() {
  phase = frameCount / 2; // deklarierung in der Funktion
  if (transition.ing) { 
    transition.t++; // increment um 1
    if (transition.t < TRANSITION_DURATION) {
      ns[0] = lerp(transition.oX, transition.tX, transition.t / TRANSITION_DURATION);
      ns[1] = lerp(transition.oY, transition.tY, transition.t / TRANSITION_DURATION);
    } else {
      transition.ing = false;
      transition.t = 0;
    }
  }
  if (phase % DURATION == 0 && !DEBUG) {
    var nextLook = (look + 1 <= ENK.length-2) ? look + 1 : 1;
    changeLook(nextLook);
  }
}


// DRAW wird immer wieder aufgerufen
function draw() {
  
  update();
  drawBackground();

  var col;
  
  // Hier Datenänderung, durch Farbwechsel?
  // Linienmenge, evt in Variable packen und mit je nach Phase spielen (5,10,15,20)
  for (var y = 0; y < height; y += 10) { 
    col = lerpColor(C.a, C.b, y / height);
    drawPerlinCurve(width + 50, y, phase, col);
  }
  
  // ..oder du kreeierst einen zweiten for-loop (Daten)
  for (var z = 2; z < height; z += 8) { 
    // col = lerpColor( color(60, 90, 255), color(255, 70, 107), z / height);
    col = lerpColor(C.c, C.d, z / height); 
    drawPerlinCurve(width + 50, z, phase, col);
  }
  
   capture();


}


// KEYPRESSED
function keyPressed() {
  
  if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
    changeLook(look + 1);
    if (look === 0) changeLook(1);
  }
  if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
    changeLook(look - 1);
  }
  if (keyCode === ENTER) {
    //save('pix.tiff');
  }
  
}


// CHANGE LOOK
function changeLook( id ) {
  var x, y;
  
  if (id > 0 && id <= ENK.length-2) {
    x = ENK[id] - ENK[id-1];
    y = WNK[id-1] - ENK[id-1];
  } else {
    if (DEBUG) console.log(`No Look #${id} found!`);
    ns[0] = 0.004; 
    ns[1] = 0.003; 
    id = 0;
  }
  
  if (x && y) {
    // if (DEBUG) console.log(`${x} : ${y}`);
    transition.tX = map(x, -0.09, 2.1, 0.002, 0.009);
    transition.tY = map(y, 3.7, 7.1, 0.002, 0.009);
    startTransition();
    if (DEBUG) console.log(`X: ${ns[0]}, Y: ${ns[1]}`);
  }
  
  look = id;
  if (DEBUG) console.log(`New Look! #${id}`);

}


// DRAW BACKGROUND
function drawBackground() {
  push();
    drawGradientBackground(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight, C.bg1, C.bg2);
    //drawGradientBackground(0,0, windowHeight, windowWidth, windowHeight, C.bg2, C.bg3);
  pop();
}


// DRAW GRADIENT BACKGROUND
function drawGradientBackground( x, y, w, h, c1, c2 ) {
  noFill();
  for (var i = y; i <= y + h; i++) { // Variable innerhalb der Funktion
    var inter = map(i, y, y + h, 0, 0); //Variable innerhalb der Funktion
    var c = lerpColor(C.bg1, C.bg2, inter); // Variable innerhalb der Funktion
    stroke(c);
    line(x, i, x + w, i);
  }
}


// DRAW PERLIN CURVE
function drawPerlinCurve( x, y, phase, myColour ) {
  push();
    stroke(myColour);
    beginShape();
      for (var i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
        curveVertex(x, y);
        var angle = 2 * PI * noise(x * ns[0], y * ns[1], phase * ns[2]);
        x += cos(angle) * STEPS;
        y += sin(angle) * STEPS;
      }
    endShape();
  pop();
}


// START TRANSITION
function startTransition() {
  transition.oX = ns[0];
  transition.oY = ns[1];
  transition.t = 0;
  transition.ing = true;
}
```

Comment: Unless you can show us the relevant code it is difficult to troubleshoot why that is. Where are the files being downloaded from?

Comment: I edited the post and added the code

Comment: What kind of `.tar`-files is it trying to download, and from where, @Swissdude?

Comment: It's an arbitrary filename like `8388c639-8b4f-1097-4d88-5246a8b7de11.tar`, size around 400MB and the browser says it's from `blob:` - the script runs for about 2-3 minutes before the download request is presented.

Comment: Can you try to download `ccapture.js` and serve it yourself, as a test?

Comment: did that - didn't help... :(